# Can't Preview my mobilefirst application

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I've created a project & application, and deployed successfully. But When I click Run As->Preview, it runs with no error and it is taking me to wordpad and pops up "Failed to load document".

If I run the project on server it again get deployed successfully but it is giving no output. How do I fix this?

Comment: Wordpad...? Something is very wrong in your installation. Try Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server, and then right-click on the Project icon and select to open the MobileFirst Console. Then try to preview your application's web resources. Does it work?

Comment: successfully deployed when i did run on server. But when I open MobileFirst Console,it goes to wordpad and pops up "Failed to load document".

Comment: What goes to wordpad? Try with a different browser

Comment: nothing goes to wordpad, try with different browser means?

Comment: Can you please explain how can I run using browser?

Comment: Open your bowser, chrome, and write: http://localhost:10080/worklightconsole

Comment: 404 error is coming..

Comment: Your server is supposed to be running; you can also go to eclipse > preferences > web browser and select to use an external browser.

Comment: that time i was using xamp tomcat so 404 error. but now i am using mobilefirst server ,its telling web page is not available :(

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there. Follow the tutorials. I don't know why you're even using xampchere at all.

Comment: I've checked external browser too. Still its not. and my server is running. Its giving Unable to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go over the Getting Started training materials in the MobileFirst Platform Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started/

---

I am uncertain why you would even need XAMP here when you're using MobileFirst Platform. It is completely unneeded. Close it.

Open Eclipse Java EE Kepler/Luna and make sure that you have MobileFirst Platform Studio installed (you can obtained from the Eclipse Marketplace (help > marketplace)).

Then, click the mobilefirst button from the top toolbar and create a New MobileFirst project > application.

Right-click the generated *application* folder (your-project\apps\your-app) and select Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server).

Right-click the generated *project* folder and select Open MobileFirst Console

You should then see the console and by click "preview web resources" you will see the application's default template.

---

You can also verify the server is running by opening the Servers view in Eclipse and making sure to select the server and click the green 'play' button to start the server.

Also, try in the eclipse preferences to set the browser to an external one.

Comment: hey,thanks.. I tried with simple hello worklight project. It runs on mobilefirst Development server and deployed successfully. But console is giving there is no operations to display(at the right side space). localhost:10080//worklightconsole is worked with displaying mobileFirst platform login form.

Comment: Hey,thanks a lotttt.. finally it is worked in external browser :)